# How to join two tables in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I've been searching all over the place and couldn't find a solution. I want to join two tables in SilverStripe. It's very simple:

```
class Module extends DataObject {
    ...
    static $has_one = array(
        'Website' => 'Website'
    );
    ...
}
class Website extends DataObject {
    ...
    static $has_many = array(
        'Modules' => 'Module'
    );
    ...
}
```

I want to join these two, and get all the attributes in one DataList. The `leftJoin()` function won't do anything, and it's mentioned in their website that

> Passing a $join statement to will filter results further by the JOINs performed against the foreign table. It will not return the additionally joined data.

I tried to use raw query

```
DB::query('SELECT * FROM "Module" LEFT JOIN "Website" ON "Website"."ID" = "Module"."WebsiteID"');
```

but all I got was this

> MySQLQuery Object ( [handle:protected] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 19 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 5 [type] => 0 ) [currentRecord:protected] => [rowNum:protected] => -1 [queryHasBegun:protected] => )

Anyone has any idea how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: First: this has nothing todo with jquery, second: you used the raw query, you'll get the query object - so proceed from there: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/2.4/reference/sqlquery/

Comment: Sorry, I mistook it for 'query'. I've tried SQLQuery(), but it's giving me the same result as using raw query. I'm using SS 3.2 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around. It's not the perfect solution for joining two tables, especially when there are a lot of attributes, but it does give me what I want for now.

```
$modules = Module::get();

$list = new ArrayList();

foreach($modules as $module) {
    $website = Website::get()->filter(array(
        'ID' => $module->WebsiteID
    ))->first();

    $array = array("mName" => $module->Name,
                    "mDes" => $module->Description,
                    "wName" => $website->Name);
    $list->push($array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You indeed cannot get the joined data through the default ORM. If you, however, choose to decide to use the `DB::Query()`, you can easily fetch them as an array. 
An example:

```
                $items = DB::Query("
                            SELECT 
                               Module.Title,
                               Website.URL
                            FROM Module
                            LEFT JOIN Website ON Website.ID = Module.WebsiteID
                ");
                if($items) {
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach($items as $item) {
                        $moduleTitle = $item['Title'];
                        $websiteURL = $item['URL'];
                    }
                }
```

This option is faster than the workaround you suggested. If you need an ArrayList because you want to use the data in a template, build the ArrayList yourself, or use a snippet like [this](http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/52fd61e09c10b).

Comment: Hi @Terry, I already tried it but when I use `Debug::show($items)` I only got `MySQLQuery::__set_state(array( 'handle' => mysqli_result::__set_state(array( 'current_field' => NULL, 'field_count' => NULL, 'lengths' => NULL, 'num_rows' => NULL, 'type' => NULL, )), 'currentRecord' => NULL, 'rowNum' => -1, 'queryHasBegun' => false, ))`

Comment: Just from the top of my mind you should run it like $result = $items->execute(); Debug::dump($items) probably dumps out the SQL query object not the executed state.

Comment: Seems that with DB:Query you need to get the the result with $items->value(). Thought with SQLQuery you should be able to get the joined fields data also if you look at the link above. Can't test that at the moment my self.

Comment: Hi @DimSum, that's correct. If you var_dump or use Debug::show you get information about the connection and results. But you can still iterate over those results using foreach(). Try this: `foreach($items as $item) { Debug::show($item); }`